# Error on the Freeform plugin

Tags: plugin-freeform

I got this error on the website and the site is working fine and suddenly I can see this.

> "Undefined class constant 'EVENT_AFTER_VALIDATE"
>
> vendor/solspace/craft-freeform/packages/plugin/src/Bundles/Payments/Stripe/StripePaymentsBundle.php

Please can anyone assist/provide us any solution to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the error occurred after updating the plugins. Most likely, the composer somehow incorrectly installed the update. Could it be a permissions issue, or is the version of PHP in Composer different from the version of PHP being used?
I see that [this constant is in the plugin repository](https://github.com/solspace/craft-freeform/blob/master/packages/plugin/src/Library/Composer/Components/Form.php#L88).

Check if you have this file locally in the vendor folder.

```
/vendor/solspace/craft-freeform/packages/plugin/src/Library/Composer/Components/Form.php
```